# How can i use RN-Fetch-Blob to read json from sdcard

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

I have a noob question, I'm trying to read the [movies.json of Facebook](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json) 
but from a sdcard.. i'm using RN-Fetch-Blob

```
RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile("file:///storage....", 'utf-8')
.then((data) => {
let id0 = data.movies[0].id;
})
```

but this is not working, how is the right way to read the id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the type of data is string so you need to use JSON.parse(data)

```
RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile("file:///storage....", 'utf-8')
.then((data) => {
const newData = JSON.parse(data);
newData.movies[0].id;
})
```